# Uniform boundedness in proving uniform convergence

Tags: calculus, analysis

Given a function series $U_k^{(n)}: \Bbb C\rightarrow \Bbb C$
$$
U_k^{(n)}(x) = (2n+1)\sin\frac{x}{2n+1}\bigg(1-\frac{\sin^2\frac{x}{2n+1}}{\sin^2\frac{\pi}{2n+1}}\bigg)...\bigg(1-\frac{\sin^2\frac{x}{2n+1}}{\sin^2\frac{k\pi}{2n+1}}\bigg)
$$

We want to show $U_k^{(n)}$ is bounded (either pointwise or uniform).
The context here is that we want to prove the uniform convergence of Euler's formula $$\sin x=x\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-x^2/(n^2\pi^2))$$ on any closed circle {$x\in \Bbb C: |x|\le A$}. We introduced $U_k^{(n)}$ since as $n$ increases, $U_k^{(n)}$ converges to $U_k$ (see the definition of $U_k$ in Q4 below), and $U_k$ converges to the infinite product in Euler's formula. The original problem may seems difficult but it is divided into easier parts. I'll walk it through briefly in case anyone is interested in the steps:

Q1. Show that $\forall n\in \Bbb N$, there is a $p\in \mathcal P_n(\Bbb C)$ that $\forall x\in \Bbb C$, $\sin(2n+1)x = \sin x \cdot p(\sin^2 x)$ and $p(0)=2n+1$.  (By induction)

Q2. Show that $u_j=\sin^2 (j\pi/(2n+1)), j=1,...,n$ are $n$ distinct roots for $p$. (Plug $u_j$ into the equation in Q1)

Q3. Show that $\forall x\in \Bbb C\forall k < n$, $\sin x = U_k^{(n)}V_k^{(n)}$ where$$V_k^{(n)} =\bigg(1-\frac{\sin^2\frac{x}{2n+1}}{\sin^2\frac{(k+1)\pi}{2n+1}}\bigg)...\bigg(1-\frac{\sin^2\frac{x}{2n+1}}{\sin^2\frac{n\pi}{2n+1}}\bigg)$$
(use Q2)

Q4. Prove the pointwise convergence of $U_k^{(n)}$:$\forall x\in \Bbb C\forall k \in \Bbb N$,$$U_k=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}U_k^{(n)}(x)=x\prod_{n=1}^k(1-x^2/(k^2\pi^2))$$ ($k$ is finite and use $\sin x / x \rightarrow 1$)

Q5. Prove the pointwise convergence of $V_k^{(n)}$:$\forall x\in \Bbb C\forall \epsilon >0\exists N\in \Bbb N\forall k\ge N\forall n>k$,$$|V_k^{(n)}-1|<\epsilon$$ This might be tricky. We used the fact that $\forall \alpha_j\in \Bbb C(1\le j\le n),$ $$|1-(1-\alpha_1)...(1-\alpha_n)|\le \sum_{j=1}^n (|\alpha_1|+...+|\alpha_n|)^j$$ and $$\bigg|\frac{\sin^2\frac{x}{2n+1}}{\sin^2\frac{j\pi}{2n+1}}\bigg|\le\frac{|x|^2}{4j^2}K^2\bigg(\frac{|x|}{2n+1}\bigg)$$ where $K(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$ is continuous on $\Bbb C$ and $K(0)=1$.

So far so good, the previous 5 problems I have no issue with. Now we need to prove the uniform convergence of $U_k$ to $\sin x$. Here are my thoughts. Notice that
$$
|U_k(x)-\sin x| = |U_k - U_k^{(n)}V_k^{(n)}| \\ \le |U_k - U_k^{(n)}| + |U_k^{(n)}||1-V_k^{(n)}|
$$
In Q4 and Q5 we have proved the pointwise convergence of $U_k^{(n)}$ and $V_k^{(n)}$, so in order to prove the pointwise convergence of $U_k$ we need $U_k^{(n)}$ to be pointwise bounded. This is easy since $|U_k^{(n)}| = |\sin x| / | V_k^{(n)}|$.

Now to prove the uniform convergence on the closed circe {$|x|\le A$}, as $\sin x$ is uniform bounded, I guess the technique of Q5 can be extended to show that $V_k^{(n)}$ has uniform convergence and thus $|V_k^{(n)}|$ has a uniform lower bound as long as $k$ is large enough? And still we need to extend Q4's result into uniform convergence. Another idea is to use Dini's theorem. I'm mainly confused in proving the uniform convergence from the pointwise convergence.

My intuition is that as the circle {$|x|\le A$} is closed and bounded, all the constants we used in Q4, Q5 to prove pointwise convergence (which depends on $x$) can be substituted by a constant for all {$|x|\le A$}.